# Clear contents of Columns A through H from first row where Col G = - down through row 50000

Tags: excel, vba

Having tried for many hours without a solution, I am asking for help to please clear the contents of Columns A through H from first row where Col G = - to row 50000.  I have tried many approaches without success.  Users currently have instructions to do this manually, but I sure wish it could be automated by adding it to the code below.  Deleting the rows is no good because it upsets array formulas elsewhere that use this data.

```
Sub CopyPasteToPrYrData()
'
' CopyPasteToPrYrData Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    Sheets("Barrel List by Producer").Range("AD3:AK30000").Copy
    Sheets("Prior Years Data").Range("A1:H29998").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Sheet1.Activate
    Range("A1:B29998").Select
        With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    
End With

    Range("A1:H29998").Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    
    
End Sub
```

I tried creating a concatenated range formula in Excel from calculated Find values, code to copy the first row with only a space in it and copying that down, building a range formula in VBA instead of Excel, and various iterations of those until I gave up on my ability to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use AutoFilter() to filter negative values and clear them

here's a possible code, where I also refactored your existing one to add more consistency

```
Sheets("Barrel List by Producer").Range("AD3:AK17").Copy
With Sheets("Prior Years Data")
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    With .Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        .NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
        
        .Sort Key1:=.Range("G1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
        
        .AutoFilter field:=7, Criteria1:="<0"
            With .Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
                If CBool(Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(1))) Then
                    .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).ClearContents
                End If
            End With
    End With
    .AutoFilterMode = False
End With
```

Comment: Thank you for your efforts, user3598756, but that did not work and only highlighted down to row 17 without accomplishing the work that it was doing before.  I do not have any negative values, but use "-" because it is key to other calcs in the system.

Comment: can you add a screenshot of your data after sorting?

Comment: Thank you, again, user3598756, but I had already determined the needed actions to solve the problem.  After not fighting it for a while, I was able to solve it and post answer.  I am grateful for the gift of your time and energy!

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyPasteToPrYrData()
'
' CopyPasteToPrYrData Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+C
'
    Sheets("Barrel List by Producer").Range("AD3:AK30000").Copy
    Sheets("Prior Years Data").Range("A1:H29998").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    Sheet1.Activate
    Range("A1:B29998").Select
        With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
        .Value = .Value
    
End With

    Range("A1:H29998").Sort Key1:=Range("G1"), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlNo
    
    Columns("G:G").Select
    Selection.Find(What:="-", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
    ActiveCell.EntireRow.Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    
End Sub
```

Comment: is this the solution?